# $wpdb query outputs php code instead of executing it

Tags: wpdb, sql

I'm using the following code in WordPress HTML page in Azure:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php
 global $wpdb;
 $result = $wpdb -> get_results ( "
 SELECT 'VillageLeadersName' 
 FROM wp_villageleaderdb 
 WHERE VillageID = 'V001' AND VillageLeaderPosition = 'Sarpanch' LIMIT 0, 100
 " );
 echo $result;
 echo $row['VillageLeadersName'] . "<br />";
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The following image shows the resulting screen:
[image]

The query works fine on admin console. The resulting page shows the code instead of results. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Hi. Please also add some of the results to your questing by using [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/276515/edit) edit link. I'm not sure what do you mean by code, unless we have a look at it.

Comment: What do you mean by WordPress HTML page? Are you adding this to the Text editor when editing a page? That won't work. You can't use PHP there.

Comment: By html I mean is that to be put in the wordpress page.  The resulting screen start showing the code from get_results on wards.

Comment: @jacob-peattie  Please advise on how to get this done. Do I have to put it in a .php file in the www root? If so how do I call the php code in the wordoress page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very clear that your file is not executing PHP functions, and the problem probably is because you are saving this file as `something.html`, storing it inside your theme or WordPress installation directory.

What you can do, is to wrap this as a function or shortcode, and then create a page and use that shortcode or function inside it.

Here is a simple example to develop shortcode from your query:

```
add_shortcode('my-shortcode', 'create_my_shortcode');
function create_my_shortcode(){
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb -> get_results ( "
        SELECT 'VillageLeadersName' 
        FROM wp_villageleaderdb 
        WHERE VillageID = 'V001' AND VillageLeaderPosition = 'Sarpanch' LIMIT 0, 100
        " );
    return $result[0][1] . "<br />";
}
```

Put this code inside your theme's `functions.php` file, and then head over to `New > Page` and create a page. Afterward, you can use this shortcode inside your page:

```
[my-shortcode]
```

This will execute and output your code. Also note that you can not `echo` content in a shortcode, you must `return` it.

Another approach is to simply wrap it as a function without creating a shortcode, and then call that function inside your templates.

```
function create_my_shortcode(){
    // Your code here
}
```

Now, make a copy of your theme's `page.php`, rename it to `page-whatever.php` and modify it the way you like. After you finished editing, use `create_my_shortcode()` anywhere you want. In this method you can `echo` the content too.

Afterward, you can use this template while creating a new page in the back-end.

### UPDATE

As stated in your comments, the results might be an array. To print the array, you can use a foreach like this:

```
$data = '';
foreach( $result as $single_result ){
    $data .= $single_result;
}
return $data. $row['VillageLeadersName'] . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web server has probably some misconfiguration regarding the execution of PHP files, but regardless, what you are trying to do probably falls under "doing it wrong". Front end HTML generating files should almost always be part of a theme, what you probably need to do is to develop a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) to be used for this specific page.

Comment: Thank you for indicating the direction, but it is some thousand leagues above me. Can you please provide an example template I could use

Comment: it is really all in the link that is in the answer. You should try to read, understand and implement it, it is not conceptually compex, just several step that should be followed

Comment: Sorry this is not an answer.